# Nodejs createDecipher, can decrypt same ciphertext with two different keys

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl

While using Nodejs createDecipher I am seemingly able to decrypt the same ciphertext data payload without error using two different keys.

```
var ciphertext = '31c655f86b39fc9ac1dd96d7ae5e9d905e7c977df9ea70e6b87d3504caf03760';

var key1 = 'asdf';
var key2 = '8bc94f258d9aaf509061b5ff52bfeb019ce802959c41eaa188beacd5e33f21db';

function decrypt(data, key) {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', key);

    var decrypted = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf8');
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
    return decrypted;
}

// 890736.159999999
console.log(decrypt(ciphertext, key1));
// ������F������쭳����M2�����C�<
console.log(decrypt(ciphertext, key2));
```

When decrypting with the second key I expect a `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt` error to be produced.  In fact when I change a single character in the second key an error is produced:

```
crypto.js:153
  var ret = this._handle.final();
                         ^

Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Error (native)
    at Decipher.Cipher.final (crypto.js:153:26)
    at decrypt (/Users/user/decrypt.js:8:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/decrypt.js:13:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:148:18)
```

using the second key: `8bc94f258d9aaf509061b5ff52bfeb019ce802959c41eaa188beacd5e33f21dd`

Although no error is thrown, the decrypted value produced by the second key is not correct, 890736.159999999 is expected.

I have tried using Node 6.10.3, 4.4.6 and 5.10 on a Mac.
I have also tried using Node 6.10.3 in a docker container running amazon linux.

According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password): `The implementation of crypto.createDecipher() derives keys using the OpenSSL function EVP_BytesToKey with the digest algorithm set to MD5, one iteration, and no salt.`  Am I possibly seeing a md5 collision?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password) it is?  `The implementation of crypto.createDecipher() derives keys using the OpenSSL function EVP_BytesToKey with the digest algorithm set to MD5, one iteration, and no salt. ` Keys can be variable in length with no error.  Im assuming its using a older version, 128bit key coming from the md5 derivation.  I can absolutely file a issue.

Comment: Well, looking at Node.js [Crypto API](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html), you are using `crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password)`. I guess that explains it.

Comment: Hmm so the md5 derivation is colliding producing the same key? If so, this seems like a pretty large security vulnerability.  The createDecipher method doesn't appear deprecated (and its all over the internet), but they do recommend not to use it.

Comment: Probably not. I'm guessing (and its just a guess), you are getting lucky with the padding. You happened to find a key which, when the message is decrypted, the padding happens to be right. Try the same experiment with GCM mode. Its deterministic and its a lot harder to get lucky.

Comment: Gotcha.  Is there any documentation you could link me to which would explain that step in the process or how padding is applied to my key? Should I just read the OpenSSL docs? Appreciated.

Comment: Padding is applied to the data. The key derivation function creates a key of the correct length from any length password you supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with MD5 collision and everything to do with the padding which is [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) by default in node.js.

The unpadding procedure works by removing the last bytes that all have the same value. The value of the last byte directly determines how many bytes need to be removed. If it has the value 0x02 then 2 bytes are removed. The other bytes in the padding are checked whether they have the same value as the last byte. If this check fails, you get an error.

If you decrypt with a wrong key (or password as in this case), you produce arbitrary random-looking bytes before unpadding. Then the unpadding procedure will try to remove the padding and likely fail. But there are cases where it might not fail. The very last byte can be a 0x01 value which means that it is already a valid padding. This can happen with a probability of 1 in 256.

**Don't use the padding procedure as a way of checking whether your key was correct.** Instead, you should use authentication either through an authenticated mode like GCM or EAX, or through a message authentication code (MAC) like HMAC-SHA256.

Answer (score 2):

Since the second decryption data is incorrect it has **not** decrypted correctly.

The plaintext is 16 bytes
There will be 16 bytes of padding added thus 32 bytes of encrypted data
The encrypted data is 64 hex characters or 32 bytes.

So all this make sense.

Now for the error, I suspect you are getting a padding error with the incorrect key, that is the padding is not consistent. See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

A padding error is **not** a valid check for a correct encryption key. If you need a check for successful encryption you need to add authentication.